# Access a git server using SSH from a hop machine

Tags: git, networking, ssh, tunnel

I have 3 machines labeled 1, 2 and 3 respectively

1. My development machine that does all the heavylifting (Windows / Have admin access)
2. My work laptop that has vpn access to the company network (Windows / Don't have admin access)
3. A company development server that I have setup with git (Ubuntu / Have admin access)

I basically want to be able to push our repositories from machine 1 into machine 3 then commit directly. I can use SSH to do this from machine 2 to 3 using the company vpn. However, machine 1 and 2 are on the same physical network, so surely I can setup some kind of routing from machine 1->2->(through vpn)3.

(The alternative to this is that I do development on the crummy laptop (machine 2) and have the machine sent away for a while to have the software I need installed on it)

I've looked at reverse SSH tunneling but I'm not quite sure that is what I need to do. I'm not very network savvy, more into the software side of things, so any advice is appreciated!

I've tried somethign akin to the below, however I'm just gettong connection timed out so I must be going about this wrong.

```
ssh -L 3333:amelia.magee@{machine3localip}:22 amelia.magee@{machine2localip}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not specify credentials when describing the tunnel :

```
ssh -L 3333:{machine3localip}:22 {machine2localip}
```

I think you already did this, just mentionning : `machine3localip` would be the ip as seen by machine 2.

You should then try :

```
ssh amelia.magee@localhost:3333
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `amelia.magee@` after `3333:`, it's not valid.

`ssh -L 3333:{machine3localip}:22 amelia.magee@{machine2localip}`

Here is an excellent answer about ssh tunnel: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118650/162326